# Transformar decimal em binário PHP

Tags: php, ip

Estou desenvolvendo uma calculadora IP em PHP. O problema é que, quando é digitado uma máscara em decimal, exemplo "255.255.255.0" a máscara em binário é exibida "1111111111111111111111110" pois usei a função do php DECBIN que transforma decimal em binário. O problema é que fazendo dessa forma, os oito bits do último octeto não são exibidos, pois o último número é "0" em decimal. Abaixo está meu código. Alguém sabe de uma forma para transformar com 32 bits?

```
 $mascara_decimal = array("", "", "", "");
                $mascara_decimal = explode(".", $_POST["mascara"]);
                $mascara_binario = array("", "", "", "");
                echo "Máscara em decimal:&nbsp;";
                echo $_POST["mascara"];
                echo"<br>";
                echo "Máscara em binário:&nbsp;";
                for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
                    $mascara_binario[$i] = decbin($mascara_decimal[$i]);
                    echo $mascara_binario[$i];
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize-se do [str_pad](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php):

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
      $mascara_binario[$i] = str_pad(decbin($mascara_decimal[$i]), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
      echo $mascara_binario[$i];
 }
```

Ele preencherá os zeros (0) faltantes.

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode usar o `ip2long()` para converter para decimal.

Dessa forma:

```
$decimal = ip2long('255.255.255.0');
```

Então pode converter de decimal para binário usando o `decbin` e depois usar o `str_pad` como usando na solução do @Everson. Uma outra opção é usar simplesmente o `sprintf`:

```
echo sprintf('%032b', ip2long('255.255.255.0'));
// Resultado: 11111111111111111111111100000000
```

[Teste isto](https://ideone.com/kjbSgx)